# I can not order tree.panel in extjs

Tags: sorting, extjs, tree

```
    var storeTree = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax'
        },
        root: {
            text: "Viviendas",
            id: 'root',
            expanded: true,
            children: []
        },
        sortOnLoad: true,
        sorters: [{
            property: 'text',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],
        folderSort: true
     });

var treeVivi = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'idTreeViviEdif',
    title : "Impresión",
    store : storeTree,
    rootVisible: false, 
    useArrows: true,
    folderSort: true,
    draggable: false,
    scroll: true
});
```

I created a tree.panel on fly, I have tried everything to sort tree.panel, but I can not, I can help someone to order?

greetings and thanks ....

Comment: what you mean order! if you mean order of the nodes, you should handle in store.

Comment: my tree is root-> first level-> second level..., l want order, second level

Comment: where is the node definitions? I mean `children`. You should define in `TreeStore`

Comment: I do not understand you, an example, please

Comment: Check out the doc please. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel